# How to create a full circle vector that its fill/stroke color changes along the path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

I would like to know how to color change a stroke in Illustrator or Photoshop like the Q in the picture:

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you want a circle with a gradient stroke?

Comment: Yes. The color changes along the path. So for example, along the path, yellow changes itself to green, green to blue, blue to red.

Comment: If the link above your question doesn't help please edit your question to show us what you've tried and why it isn't what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a gradient to a stroke as well as a fill.

Comment: you can get greater control of the stroke if you expand it